# How to define a variable based on an if/then/else statement

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, if-statement

I'm trying to translate some python code to haskell. However I reached a point where I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
if len(prod) % 2 == 0:
    ss = float(1.5 * count_vowels(cust))
else:
    ss = float(count_consonants(cust)) # muliplicaton by 1 is implied.

if len(cust_factors.intersection(prod_factors)) > 0:
    ss *= 1.5

return ss
```

I've tried to translate it to this:

```
if odd length prod
    then ss = countConsonants cust
    else ss = countVowels cust
if  length (cust intersect prod) > 0
    then ss = 1.5 * ss
    else Nothing
```

return ss

But I keep getting errors of:

> parse error on input `='

Any help or words of wisdom on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you everyone that posted. You all provided me with some good information and ways to think about the problem "correctly".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't think of programming in Haskell as "if this, then do that, then do the other thing" — the entire idea of *doing things in a sequence* is imperative. You're not checking a condition and then defining a variable — you're just calculating a result that depends on a condition. In functional programming, `if` is an expression and variables are assigned the result of an expression, not assigned inside it.

The most direct translation would be:

```
let ss = if odd $ length prod
         then countConsonants cust
         else countVowels cust
in if length (cust `intersect` prod) > 0
   then Just $ 1.5 * ss
   else Nothing
```

Answer (score 6):

In Haskell, `if` is an expression, not a statement. This means it returns a value (like a function) instead of performing an action. Here's one way to translate your code:

```
ss = if odd length prod 
    then countConsinants cust 
    else countVowels cust 
return if length ( cust intersect prod) > 0 
    then Just $ 1.5 * ss 
    else Nothing
```

Here's another way:

```
return if length ( cust intersect prod) > 0 
    then Just $ 1.5 * if odd length prod 
        then countConsinants cust 
        else countVowels cust 
    else Nothing
```

As Matt has pointed out, however, your Python code doesn't return `None`. Every code path sets `ss` to a number. If this is how it's supposed to work, here's a Haskell translation:

```
let ss = if odd $ length prod 
           then countConsonants cust 
           else countVowels cust 
in if length (cust `intersect` prod) > 0 
     then 1.5 * ss 
     else ss
```

Comment: Though the answer to the question is right, this isn't well-typed (`*` doesn't have the same type as `Nothing`), and I'm not sure why we'd use `return` here.

Comment: Chuck: You're right. I tried to show the proper form while minimizing the rewriting because I thought it would make it too hard to figure out what I was trying to demonstrate. Maybe I didn't go far enough, though.

Comment: Chuck, the original doesn't return nothing if the second test fails, it returns whatever the first test set ss to be. (In Python)

Comment: Good point, Matt. It's hard to tell whether the `return` was meant to be indented (as implied by his Haskell attempt) or not (as implied by the actual Python code), so I included a version that always returns a value.

Answer (score 4):

If I were you I'd use [guards](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Control_structures#Guards). Maybe I'm a Haskell heathen.

```
ss prod prodfactors cust | even $ length prod = extratest . (1.5 *) . countvowels cust
                         | otherwise          = extratest . countconsonants cust
                         where extratest curval | custfactorsintersection prodfactors > 0 = curval * 1.5
                                                | otherwise                               = curval
```

Answer (score 3):

I would write it like this in Haskell:

```
if (not $ null $ cust_factors `intersect` prod_factors)
    then ss * 1.5
    else ss
where
    ss = if (even $ length prod)
         then 1.5 * count_vowels cust
         else count_cosinants cust
```

Some comments about what you wrote:

- You can do assignment in Haskell using the `let` and `where` syntax. In general everything you write in Haskell are expressions. In your case you have to write the whole thing as a single expression and using `let` or `where` simplifies that task.
- `return` in Haskell means something different than in Python, it's used for computations with side effects (like IO). For your example there is no need for it.
- `Nothing` is a special value of the type `Maybe a`. This type represents values of type `a` with possible failure (the `Nothing`).

And to answer your direct question.
This Python code

```
if b:
  s = 1
else:
  s = 2
```

would be translated to Haskell to `s = if b then 1 else 2` inside a `let` or `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

[Functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) is different from imperative programming. Trying to "translate" line by line isn't how Haskell is meant to be used.

Comment: Doesn't answer the questions, but yeah.

Answer (score 1):

To specifically answer your question. "ss" already has a value. It simply isn't possible to give it a different value. `ss = ss * 1.5` makes no sense.